# Wordpress if/else statement on archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

For a website I am working on I've tried to do some modifications on a exciting wordpress theme (revera). The original code displayed posts on archive pages with only a thumbnail image and the post title. The following is the original code:

```
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">
         <?php $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' );     //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big) $image = aq_resize( $img_url,     750, 500, true ); //resize & crop the image  ?>
         <?php if($image) : ?> <div class="hthumb">         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img     class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a> </div> <?php endif; ?> <h3><a href="<?php     the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> 
    </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now I have made a if/ else statement in the archive.php (display below) so the archive page of some specific categories shows another code than the above mentioned.

Now, the problem is that the archive is not displaying the original code correctly anymore (archive page). The code if else statement I've made is the following (the error should be in the part after "else"):

```
<?php
    if ( is_category( 'producten-diensten' )  ) {
        echo'
             the code for producten-diensten category ';

} else {
  //everything else

 while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
     $wp_query->the_post();
     echo'<article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">';
     $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
     $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
     $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 750, 500, true ); //resize & crop the image
     if($image) : ;
        echo'<div class="hthumb"><a href="' . the_permalink() . '"><img class="img-responsive" src="' . $image . '"/></a></div>';
     endif;
     echo'<h3><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . the_title() . '</a></h3>';
     echo'</article>';
 endwhile;

}?>
```

The page (http://tinyurl.com/of2xslw) is showing the thumbnail correctly but the url of the single post to which the thumbnail should link is displayed above the thumbnail. The thumbnail links to the archive page instead of the single post page, and the title of the post (with permalink to the single post) is not displaying below the thumbnail. Instead of that, a strange url appears. The page should look like this

What is going wrong here? I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy one:

You shouldn't echo the_permalink() and the_title() as they already echo their respective results:

```
<?php
    if ( is_category( 'producten-diensten' )  ) {
        echo'
             the code for producten-diensten category ';

} else {
  //everything else

 while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
     $wp_query->the_post();
     echo'<article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">';
     $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
     $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
     $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 750, 500, true ); //resize & crop the image
     if($image) : ?>
        <div class="hthumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/></a></div>';
     <?php endif;?>
          <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
     <?php echo'</article>';
 endwhile;

}?>
```

Attention the code might not work because I don't have the library aq_resize and therefore I can't test it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Tried itbut its not working unfortunately. [link](http://www.timmerenonderhouddino.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Schermafbeelding-2014-11-19-om-21.33.17.png) I get a error on line 224. Seems as if the permalink links to the archive page instead of to the individual post. The individual post title does not show either.

Comment: @LarsLenselink I messed up while doing the copy-paste, try it now!

Comment: We are getting there! The post title now shows correctly [(check)](http://tinyurl.com/of2xslw) but some how the image links to the archive page and puts the link which it should actually link to above the image. When I check the source code, the href is empty for the image. Pretty weird.

Comment: Wow it work! The only thing what was incorrect was the '; behind the image div. I've deleted it and everything looks good now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LarsLenselink Yes, I said it wasn't possible for me to debug it properly because I didn't had some libraries you're using such as the aq_resize(). Good to see it working, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Final correct code was (thanks to nunorbatista):

```
<?php
    if ( is_category( 'producten-diensten' )  ) {
        echo'
             the code for producten-diensten category ';

} else {
  //everything else

 while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
     $wp_query->the_post();
     echo'<article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">';
     $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
     $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
     $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 750, 500, true ); //resize & crop the image
     if($image) : ?>
        <div class="hthumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/></a></div>';
     <?php endif;?>
          <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
     <?php echo'</article>';
 endwhile;

}?>
```